# adjusting width of bar in bar chart for swift charts(not new swift charts lib)

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts

I am using the swift charts library found [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). When I call our api, we have anywhere from 1 data point up to 24 data points for 24 hrs in a day. When I have a lot of data our width of bars are great. When I have 1 or or up to 5 the widths are very wide and dont look good. I assume its because its trying to fill up the space. does anyone know how I could adjust it to be skinny and not take up the space.

In update view I tried to do various different zooms based on the amount of data but it seems as if there is a min zoom or something in the library.

//code below

```
import Charts
import SwiftUI

struct TransactionBarChartView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let entries: [BarChartDataEntry]
    let barChart = BarChartView()
    @Binding var selectedYear: Int
    @Binding var selectedItem: String
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> BarChartView {
        barChart.delegate = context.coordinator
        return barChart
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: BarChartView, context: Context) {
        let dataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: entries)
        dataSet.label = "Transactions"
        uiView.noDataText = "No Data"
        uiView.data = BarChartData(dataSet: dataSet)
        uiView.rightAxis.enabled = false
        /*if uiView.scaleX == 1.0 {
            uiView.zoom(scaleX: 1.5, scaleY: 1, x: 0, y: 0)
        }*/
        if entries.count < 8 {
            uiView.zoom(scaleX: 0.2, scaleY: 1, x: 0, y: 0)
        }
        if entries.count < 4 {
                    uiView.zoom(scaleX: 0.2, scaleY: 1, x: 0, y: 0)
                }
        if entries.count < 2 {
            uiView.zoom(scaleX: 0.0005, scaleY: 1, x: 0.05, y: 0)
        }
        uiView.setScaleEnabled(false)
        formatDataSet(dataSet: dataSet)
        formatLeftAxis(leftAxis: uiView.leftAxis)
        formatXAxis(xAxis: uiView.xAxis)
        formatLegend(legend: uiView.legend)
        uiView.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ChartViewDelegate {
        let parent:TransactionBarChartView
        init(parent: TransactionBarChartView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
            let month = WineTransaction.months[Int(entry.x)]
            let quantity = Int(entry.y)
            parent.selectedItem = "\(quantity) sold in \(month)"
            
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    func formatDataSet(dataSet: BarChartDataSet) {
        dataSet.colors = [.red]
        dataSet.valueColors = [.red]
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .none
        dataSet.valueFormatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: formatter)
    }
    
    func formatLeftAxis(leftAxis: YAxis) {
        leftAxis.labelTextColor = .red
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .none
        leftAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(formatter: formatter)
        leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    }
    
    func formatXAxis(xAxis: XAxis) {
        xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: WineTransaction.months)
        xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        xAxis.granularityEnabled = true

        xAxis.labelTextColor = .red
    }
    
    func formatLegend(legend: Legend) {
        legend.textColor = .red
        legend.horizontalAlignment = .right
        legend.verticalAlignment = .top
        legend.drawInside = true
        legend.yOffset = 30.0
        
    }
   
}
```

[image: wide bars with little data]

[image: width we want no matter the amount of data we have]